# Showing it is a joint probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X,Y$ with a joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=x+y$ if $(x,y)\in[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and otherwise $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$

I want to analyze this case in different cases, first of all, I want to show it is a probability density function. Well I think the best way is to calculate it $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y\mid X}(y|x)f_X(x) = f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)f_Y(y)$ but how can we evaluate the condtional and marginal distributions ?

Another idea is to show $\int_x \int_y f_{X,Y}(x,y) \; dy \; dx= 1.$

In the next step I would like to determine the cumulative distributions $F_X(x), F_Y(y)$

Comment: you can use the double integral it is simple and will give you $1$. Since your function is continuous and positive, then you can conclude that it is indeed a density

Comment: Do you also have an idea for the cumulative distributions?

Comment: read wikipedia please. $F_x$ is the integral of $f_x$. can you obtain $f_x$ and $f_y$ first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you should check that 
   $$\int_0^1\int_0^1(x+y)\,dydx=1\,.$$
2. By definition, $F_X(t)=P(X<t)$, and this can be expressed by the integral:
   $$F_X(t)=\int_0^t\int_0^1 (x+y)\,dydx\,.$$

Comment: Thanks, how can things like $P[X=1/2,Y=1/2]$, $P[X=Y]$ and $P[x\le 1/2, Y\le 1/2]$ expressed using the integrals? I know that we con da it using the cumulative distributin function F(x,y) but I do not know how.